# How does the circuit of ITD(Time delay) and voltage sense works?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ac, voltage-measurement, delay

I have designed the schematic of ITD(Intelligent time delay) and voltage sense by tracing the circuit of AC Guard unit in which it senses the voltage and cut off the supply based on predefined upper and lower limit.

*It features a start up delay of about 4 minutes to prevent frequent switching on and off during fluctuations. The A/C Guard has the advanced feature to save on down time. It means that when the mains returns to normal after any event, the A/C Guard checks the duration of the OFF time. If the unit has been off for more than 4 minutes then it will switch the air-conditioner on within 10 seconds rather than the standard 4 minutes. If however, the unit has been off for less than 4 minutes, the A/C Guard will ensure that it will remain off up to 4 minutes and then restarts automatically.*

**Following is the schematic of the same, ITD goes to the MCU(ADC).**

[image]

---

**Another schematic is of voltage sensing :**

[image]

Now my query is how do both the circuit works, and how can I measure the OFF time of the unit using the ITD circuit using Microcontroller? I want to understand the work follow of this circuit.

Also what will be the value of D5 and D6 Diodes, will they be zener or simple 1N4007 diode?

Answer (score 1):

With the first circuit, there is no means to charge C8 other than the ITD pin being held low by the microcontroller. Assuming the circuit is correct, this must be what the original unit does.

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html

describes RC time constants. C8 is the capacitor and R8 is the discharge resistor. If the system is powered (5V) and ITD is held low, then the capacitor charges via R9 and D5. The operation of D5 can be ignored for the purposes of the calculation.
D5 & D6 are most likely schottky diodes. Something like a BAT85. Don't be tempted to use a larger schottky diode like a 1N5819 as the leakage might be significant.

C8 will eventually be fully charged. When the power is removed, D5 will block any other discharge path and C8 will discharge via R8. This determines the 4 minutes (or so - it won't be super accurate).

When powered on, depending on the charge left on C8 (let's assume it is fully discharged) then the capacitor will apear as a short circuit and pass the 5V signal through D5 and R9. The microcontroller can then use it's ADC to measure the voltage which would be close to 5V (more like around 4.7V due to the diode drop of D5).
If the capacitor was fully charged (ie the circuit was not off for less than 4 minutes), the voltage at ITC will be less than 4.7V. The microcontroller code will keep on sampling that voltage until it reaches 4V or so thus creating a time delay.

once that has happened, the microcontroller would pull the ITC pin low to charge the capacitor again.

The second circuit is a half wave rectifier (D1) and a voltage divider consisting of R6,R7 and R21. based on the values the division is around 100:1. ie 100V in gives 1V out at Vsense. For a 240Vac input, Vsense will measure approximately 3.2V (240 * 1.4142 / 100). 1.4142 is the square root of two as 240VAC is the RMS value (google that) and 1.4142 determines the peak voltage.

Note that R6 & R7 have significant voltage across them. They must be adequately rated for this application. Something like a Vishay PR01 series.

It also must be said that this circuit has mains voltages present - thus it is extremely dangerous. Unless you fully understand the implications, you can easily blow up the computer you connect the circuit to or worse still electrocute yourself and/or set fire to your house. No joking.

Comment: In first circuit can I use D5 as 1N4148 schottky diode, it has drop of 1V
You said "The operation of D5 can be ignored for the purposes of the calculation",
shouldn't drop of 1V be considered in the calculations?

Also, you mentioned "the capacitor will appear as a short circuit and pass the 5V signal through D5 and R9"
there would drop of 1V incase of 1N4148, and also 1.5k R9 is in series, voltage will be further dropped,
shouldn't this resistance drop be taken into calculations?

Comment: In second circuit what is the purpose of D6, are you sure it's Schottky, not Zener diode ?

Comment: and how is the value of 4 min is achieved based on the value of cap and resistor?

Comment: No doubt D5 has an effect, but in terms of illustrating the basic operation, i suggested it be ignored.

Comment: D6 is what is called a 'clamp'. It is to stop the voltage exceeding a certain value. I'm assuming Vsense goes to an ADC pin on a 5V microcontroller so we want to ensure Vsense does not exceed the maximum input voltage of that chip. If a zener diode was used, let's assume 5V1 zener, then Vsense would be able to reach a voltage of 5V + 5V1 = 10.1V which is not good. Since a schottky diode has less forward voltage drop, then that would be the 'usual' choice and it should clamp the voltage to around 5.4V

Comment: How is the value on 4 min achieved? That's why I gave you a link in the answer. It's all about RC time constants. If in doubt, I'd suggest performing some experiments or simulating the circuit to get a better insight.

Comment: Alright can I use 1N4148 diode for D5 and D6?

Comment: You can use a 1N4148, but I wouldn’t recommend it.

Comment: Any other recommendation instead of 1n4148?

Comment: BAT85 was my first suggestion. Your application is not super critical but I would suggest using a schottky diode for low forward voltage drop rather than the usual silicon diode.